# php variables (website.com/?f="123") save to database & redirect

Tags: php, mysql

I have never coded php before and I really need this very simple script.

so let me explain what I need.
user comes to my website via affiliate link so when they finished redirecting
the url will look like this

```
http://website.com/lp/index.html?sub=1&customer_id=1039be6e23b4420c3e1063dc44a04d
```

now I have a download link on my website
On download click
check for duplicate ip address from database. if not duplicate 
capture sub="" & customer_id="" from the address bar.
save to database with IP Address (this for tracking)

and redirect immediately to the download link

if the ip is not duplicated

```
 http://dl.website.com/download/downloadpop.aspx?id={Customer_id}
```

if it's duplicated

```
http://dl.website.com/download/downloadpop.aspx?id=beenbefore
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: I want a `varibale`. They sound so cool!

Comment: @JamWaffles - They are highly dangerous, if you ever see one DO NOT approach it!

Comment: @sabre - But... But... I want one :-(

Comment: @JamWaffles lol :) it does sound funny. my mistake

Comment: @Mark - No disrespect :-) I mis-spell things all the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is rather broad, and impossible to answer properly without knowing any details about your database structure, but here's how the basics of this would work:

```
<?php

$sub = $_GET['sub'];
$customer_id = $_GET['customer_id'];
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

$db = mysql_connect(...) or die(mysql_error());

$quoted_sub = mysql_real_escape_string($sub);
$quoted_customer_id = mysql_real_escape_string($customer_id);
$quoted_ip = mysql_real_escape_string($ip);

$sql = "SELECT count(*) AS cnt FROM yourtable WHERE ip_address = '$quoted_id'";
$result = msyql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
if ($row['cnt'] == 0) {
    $enc = urlencode($customer_id);
    ... IP isn't in the database, so do the insert stuff ...
    header(" http://dl.website.com/download/downloadpop.aspx?id=$enc");
} else {
    header("Location: http://dl.website.com/download/downloadpop.aspx?id=beenbefore");
}

exit();
```

Comment: I don't have an database this looks perfect thanks a lot for the time writing this down!

Comment: do I understand it correctly this code will just read not really save ip + sub + customer_id into the database?

Comment: " $enc = urlencode($customer_id);" I just tested it and it seems that I get "http://dl.website.com/download/downloadpop.aspx?id=" with no value

Comment: that's just to prevent url injection attempts. If you get the blank query parameter, then your `$customer_id` isn't set properly in the page's original query.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want header for the redirect:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

And mysql_connect, mysql_query, etc. for DB stuff:

http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php

You can extract GET params from $_GET:

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

Note that any call to header() must take place before other output (see the example on the page linked.)

Comment: I got question for this. if they click download.php and I have $_GET['sub'] will it try to get download.php variables? Because I got the variables on the main page and I want on click for it to get it from the main page not download.php

Comment: hmm. why do the duplicate check on download click? you could just perform the duplicate check server-side and generate the link accordingly...

Answer (score 0):

First off, you can [access these variables via `$_GET()`](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/postget.php).

Next, you [INSERT them into a database using PDO](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/).

Finally, you can redirect someone with the appropriate [`header()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php):

```
header('Location:http://dl.website.com/download/downloadpop.aspx?id=beenbefore');
```

Comment: I got question for this. if they click download.php and I have $_GET['sub'] will it try to get download.php variables? Because I got the variables on the main page and I want on click for it to get it from the main page not download.php

Comment: how can I transfer variables between pages? I saw some1 had a code for session session_start() $_SESSION['sub'] = $sub; $_SESSION['customer_id'] = $customer_id; for page 1 and for page 2 $sub = $_GET['sub']; $customer_id = $_GET['customer_id']; but I get for some what reason Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE

Comment: @Mark, you haven't posted your code, I don't know how to help you.